# After gradle update to 2.10, can't run app

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.1

I'm running on Android Studio 2.1.1 and was recently asked to update the gradle plugin to 2.10 (form 2.2.1) to have the ability of instant runs, which needles to say I did. 
Right after that only one particular project can't build and I've tried everything that's available on the subject as question on stackoverflow.

Here are my settings

1. project build.gradle:

   [image]
2. gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties:

   [image]

After I try to run I get the following:

[image]

via terminal

> gradle clean --stacktrace

[image]

The last thing is pretty strange since I've set the version to 2.10
[image]

[image]

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 1):

I did my search too on this.Some said to delete the file manually but it gave me a new file everytime i did that.Try reimporting your project and rebuilding it.

Comment: Eventually this is what I ended up doing. Regardless, I hope someone has solution for this that deals with the issue more elegantly